# EF5 DB first- when creating a context object getting error that there is no key on a table but there is

Tags: entity-framework

I have an existing table that I have brought to the designer surface (EDMX). 
When I go to Add a Code Generation object and choose EF 5.x Self-tracking entity I get an error that there is no ket defined on the table even though there is as a simple identity field inthe actual table. The key also shows in the designer and is marked as an entity key in the properties.

The only thing I can think of is the name of the field may be causing the problem. ("UniqID")

Any ideas?
TIA J

This is the create script of the table in question

```
CREATE TABLE [MySchema].[ActivityStaging](
[UnqID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SEQN] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[SFDCID] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
[IMISID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[RELATEDTOIMISID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[ASSIGNEDTO] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
[ACTIVITYTYPE] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
[SUBJECT] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
[ACTIVITYDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ActivityStaging] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[UnqID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

An identity field is not a primary key. Can you script your table and paste it here. I'd like to see the key defined and also it's datatype.

Comment: I just added it to my original question.

Comment: I've created the table (omitting TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]) and loaded it into my edmx without problem. When you're adding the table to the edmx are you see just one key icon on [UnqID]? Sometimes I've seen the designer add many keys against other DB fields

Comment: It's just adding the one key.